# How do I configure the Rust Language Server via LanguageClient-neovim?

Tags: rust, neovim, rust-language-server

I am attempting to use [the Rust Language Server](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls) via [LanguageClient-neovim](https://github.com/autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim) and I want to set RLS options such as `wait_to_build`.

I do not wish to configure LanguageClient-neovim settings like how to start the RLS process.

The RLS only explains configuring [the VSCode extension](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls-vscode) via `<project>/.vscode/settings.json`.

How can I set configuration options for my server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LanguageClient-neovim allows you to configure servers via the `<project>/.vim/settings.json` file.

If this does not exist you will want to create it and track it in your version control system.

The RLS configuration options are detailed in [the project's README](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls#configuration).

The structure of your settings file should be as such:

```
{
    "rust": {
        "wait_to_build": 1500
    }
}
```

---

Once you have saved that file you will need to restart the client by issuing the command `:LanguageClientStop` then `:LanguageClientStart`.